# XML parsing of nested Arrays with PowerShell

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell, select, nested

Looking to be able to read up and down this nested array structure in XML using PowerShell and be able to Export-CSV so that the various fields targeted under each  can be read and exported out to a single record in CSV.  Including the nested .

```
<objects type="array">
<object>
    <id type="integer">1234</id>
    <name>Filename.ext</name>
    <job-actions type="array">
        <job-action>
            <id type="integer">7890</id>
            <name>job name</name>
        </job-action>
    </job-actions>
</object>

<object>
    <id type="integer">2345</id>
    <name>Filename.ext</name>
    <job-actions type="array">
        <job-action>
            <id type="integer">8901</id>
            <name> job name 1</name>
        </job-action>
        <job-action>
            <id type="integer">9012</id>
            <name>job name 2</name>
        </job-action>
    </job-actions>
</object>
</objects>
```

Get-Content and Select statements allow you target a given level (array) in the XML, but not read down to the nested level for exporting out to a single record.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the exact expected output given your sample xml?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with this example:

```
<entities>
  <animal species="dog">
    <name>Sam</name>
    <age>4</age>
    <breed>Cocker Spaniel</breed>
  </animal>
</entities>
```

and saved it in a file "entities.xml"
I first imported it by

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content "C:\temp\entities.xml"
```

And then I was able to access every attribute. E.g. the age by

```
$xml.entities.animal.age
```

My output was 4.
When using Get-Content, have you cast it as [xml] ?

Comment: Challenge is the nested array and reading the next (level below) array into the same variable / record.  Looks like my original post cut off the lines defining the first array.  Get-Content and Select statements work fine if its a single array through the XML, but its not.... <objects type="array">
  <object>
    <id type="integer">1234</id>
    <name>Filename.ext</name>
    <job-actions type="array">
     <job-action>
        <id type="integer">7890</id>
        <name>job name</name>
      </job-action>
    </job-actions>
  </object>

Comment: When I import your example now in $xml as described above, I can access every object in the array to the deepest lvl. E.g.

$xml.objects.object.'job-actions'.'job-action'.id.'#text' 

My output is: 
7890
8901
9012